# When using json_encode to display the contents of a select query, how to name objects?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Disregarding security issues (for now)

I am using json_encode to display the contents of a select query. 
I used:

```
$sql= {query code};

// created a temp array to hold data and an array for all the results
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

// looped through every object in the result set
while ($row = $result->fetch_object());

// added it into the results array
$tempArray = $row;
array_push($resultsArray, $temparray);

// encoded the array to a json format
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Question: My objects don't have names, so it makes it difficult for me to write any code that could read the results and display them. How do I name the objects? Is it an entry I could add into the table (let's say in a case of different names I could give each object)

Comment: Why don't you use `$result->fetch_array()`?

Comment: nice use for HTML CODE SNIPPET lol

Comment: Instead of $result->fetch_object() ? what would be the difference ? and how would I name the objects (I don't know where to give then names too)

Comment: Your `$row` will only ever be the *last* element in your result set.  Your `while` loop has no body, so it will loop over each element, doing nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "objects don't have names"?  Currently, your JSON is an array containing one object.  All you need to do is decode that JSON elsewhere, then loop over the array reading the object(s) inside.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I mean the results are displayed JSON format, but every result is given a number (starting from 0 and on depending on the number of results) instead of for example how I would like to be, let's say "people".

Comment: [
{
id: "1",
name: "John",
last name: "Smith",
email: "johns@domain.com",
language: "English"
},

Comment: You need to create the structure as you want it *first*, then `json_encode` it.  For example, you might want to try: `echo json_encode(array('people' => $resultArray));`  Then `people` would be an array of objects.

Comment: As above, if you edit your question with the current json and the json you would like to get, you will get a proper answer. Without those details we can only guess what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to build the array/object structure you want in PHP.  That way when you `json_encode` it, you'll know what it looks like and it will be what you want.

Try:

```
echo json_encode(array('people' => $resultArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this should not work at all. Casting `PDO` (or `MySQLi`, as mentioned in comment) objects to `JSON`. You should use `fetch_assoc` instad, that would return associative array that could be put directly in JSON structure.

Comment: Why do you think he uses PDO? He could use MySQLi as well.

Comment: Well... that does not change much ツ But thank you, edited answer.